# How to make symbolic breakpoint on popViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, breakpoints

My purpose is handle all moments when view controllers are popped out from navigation stack.
So, what symbol i must use in symbolic breakpoint to handle it?

Comment: Just click the line number that you want to add it to, you should really try to use google for this kind of question though.

Comment: pleasse explain in brief

Comment: What you want from me to explain? @Sagarkoyani

Comment: what do you mean by symbolic breakpoint?

Comment: @Sagarkoyani comment section is not an appropriate place to learn the basics of Xcode, please refer to some tutorial site instead

Comment: @mag_zbc sorry for that, i was not aware of that symbolic breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you're woking with `Swift`, make a symbolic breakpoint on `UINavigationController.popViewController`

[image]

But I wouldn't rely on symbolic breakpoints - it's better to just put breakpoint in your routing layer (i.e. a method of your subclass of `UINavigationController`)